# Why doesn't work an appropriate DTO-constructor in my JPQL-query, but returning Objects has all necessary fields?

Tags: hibernate, constructor, jpql, dto

I have an DB with Answer, Question, User and other tables. I write a method at DAO-layer which give me List, and it doesn't work with constructor "SELECT new com.example.AnswerDto( ... ) ... ".

I've tried this (*all selects must be the right ones*):

```
public List<AnswerDto> getAllAnswersDtoByQuestionId(Long questionId, Long userId) {
    return (List<AnswerDto>) entityManager.createQuery("""
        SELECT (a.id,
            a.user.id,
            a.question.id,
            a.htmlBody,
            a.persistDateTime,
            a.isHelpful,
            a.dateAcceptTime,
            COALESCE(ra.count, 0),
            COALESCE(ru.count, 0),
            a.user.imageLink,
            a.user.nickname,
            COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN v.voteType = 'UP' THEN 1 WHEN v.voteType = 'DOWN' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END), 0),
            CASE 
            WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN v.voteType = 'UP' THEN 1 WHEN v.voteType = 'DOWN' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) > 0) THEN 'UP'
            WHEN (SUM(CASE WHEN v.voteType = 'UP' THEN 1 WHEN v.voteType = 'DOWN' THEN -1 ELSE 0 END) < 0) THEN 'DOWN' END)
            FROM Answer a
            LEFT JOIN VoteAnswer v ON v.answer.id = a.id
            LEFT JOIN Reputation ra ON ra.answer.id = a.id
            LEFT JOIN Reputation ru ON ru.sender.id = :userId
            WHERE a.question.id = :questionId AND a.user.id = :userId AND a.isDeleted = false AND a.isDeletedByModerator = false
                        """)
                .setParameter("questionId", questionId)
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .getResultList();
```

But I got this in **stacktrace:**

```
nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate appropriate constructor on class [com.example.AnswerDto]. Expected arguments are: long, long, long, java.lang.String, java.time.LocalDateTime, boolean, java.time.LocalDateTime, int, int, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, long, java.lang.String
```

When I create a List, **it works fine** (but I can't convert Object to AnswerDto, although I can manually assign the Object fields to the AnswerDto constructor (like this):

```
...
                .setParameter("questionId", questionId)
                .setParameter("userId", userId)
                .getResultStream().map(e -> {
                    Object[] result = (Object[]) e;
                    return new AnswerDto(
                            (Long) result[0],
                            (Long) result[1],
                            (Long) result[2],
                            (String) result[3],
                            (LocalDateTime) result[4],
                            (Boolean) result[5],
                            (LocalDateTime) result[6],
                            (Integer) result[7],
                            (Integer) result[8],
                            (String) result[9],
                            (String) result[10],
                            (Long) result[11],
                            (VoteType) result[12]
                    );
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

It doesn't seem right enough to me. I didn't find information about this problems (**casting Object->AnswerdDto** and **inappropriate constructor in JPQL**). Just in case, here is the **AnswerDto class code**

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class AnswerDto {
    private Long id;
    private Long userId;
    private Long questionId;
    @NotEmpty
    @NotBlank
    @NotNull
    private String body;
    private LocalDateTime persistDate;
    private Boolean isHelpful;
    private LocalDateTime dateAccept;
    private Integer countValuable;
    private Integer countUserReputation;
    private String image;
    private String nickname;
    private Long countVote;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private VoteType voteType;
}
```